# Salesforce database integration(maintaining a centralized database)

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I want to integrate my application in salesforce. For that can I maintain a centralized database between salesforce and my application so that if a person register in my application through salesforce it will reflect my database?

The registration part is done with apex program.

Comment: What question are you asking here?

Comment: Actually I have used apex programming to implement the registration(Visual force for the UI and controller for business logic). In controller I can write the insertion logic to insert a record to salesforce database. But I want to save the data to my database instead of saving to salesforce database.

Comment: One way would be to implement a web service and call that from Apex - see http://wiki.developerforce.com/index.php/Apex_Web_Services_and_Callouts

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Workflow rule in Salesforce and have it send an outbound message to a web service with the details you need in your database.

The web service would need to implement the WSDL defined by the outbound message.